# Column Value not Recognized by JavaScript call in APEX Column Link

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a successful report created by the following query:

```
select '' Edit_Link, f.Unique_Allegation_ID, g.Artist, g.song_name as Song, g.owner_name as Owner, g.plaintiff_name as Plaintiff, g.premium as "Premium", g.classic as "Classic", g.restricted as "Restricted"
from tbl_unique_allegation f
left join (
  Select a.recording_id, a.Artist, a.song_name, a.premium, a.classic, a.restricted, d.owner_name, e.plaintiff_name
  from tbl_recording a
  left join tbl_recording_owner d
  on a.owner_id = d.owner_id
  left join tbl_recording_plaintiff e
  on a.plaintiff_id = e.plaintiff_id
) g
on f.recording_id = g.recording_id
```

I have set `'' Edit_Link` to target a URL:

```
javascript:test(#Unique_Allegation_ID#);
```

which calls

```
javascript:test(value){
   alert(value);
}
```

If I change the call to

```
javascript:test(3);
```

It properly alerts the value '3', but it does not alert my column value `Unique_Allegation_ID` for some reason. What is my issue?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access a variable name outside the scope of the page? If thats the case you need to set the value in session and access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One rare instance it's case sensitive, thanks to your column aliases. These demonstrate the variation:

```
javascript:test('#Premium#');
javascript:test('#UNIQUE_ALLEGATION_ID#');
```

I would not use double quotes for column aliases in APEX queries, deferring label specification to the relevant attribute.

Alternatively, you can set up a dynamic action that listens for click of your relevant cell, the selector would depend on your theme/template. Then use something like $(this.triggeringElement).text() to get value.

Comment: Definitely would encourage use of click handlers. Encapsulate necessary values in `data-` attributes in the URL. It's much more visible to anyone maintaining the page when a DA exists which handles the event, or when all click event handlers are centralized in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enclose it with single qoutation marks like this

```
javascript:test('#Unique_Allegation_ID#');
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Unfortunately that simply alerts the string '#Unique_Allegation_ID#'

Comment: what version of apex are you using?make sure your function is in the main page under javascript>functions and global variable declarations.

Comment: v4.2, I know it's in the right spot because the function is called with numeric and string values. I just can't seem to pass it a value from the row

Comment: where is this right spot?can you please elaborate?and is this how the function was written ? `javascript:test(value){
   alert(value);
}`

Comment: In Edit Page > JavaScript > functions and Global Variable Declarations. Yes, it was written just like that

Comment: remove javascript: and replace it with function `function test(value) {alert (value);}`